# Python SSL Cert Issue

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

I am trying to use censusdata and am getting a SSL cert issue below.

How can I blanket SSL removal similar to requests.get(verify=False) for packages that utilize urllib3 or requests.

```
MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.census.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /data/2015/acs/acs5?get=NAME,B23025_001E,B23025_002E,B23025_003E,B23025_004E,B23025_005E,B23025_006E,B23025_007E&for=block+group:*&in=state:36+county:081 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```